# iPhone -- is there anything like NSMutableDictionary that does not copy its keys?

Tags: iphone, nsmutabledictionary

I have a bunch of Boy objects and a bunch of Girl objects.  I want to keep a list of the girl that each boy likes the most.  It is OK if multiple boys like the same girl.

I was going to use an NSMutableDictionary, but the setObject: forKey: method of that class copies the key before adding the pair to the dictionary.  So rather than the boy liking the girl, we would have a clone of the boy liking the girl.

Normally I would do this by adding a favoriteGirl property to the Boy class.  But the problem is that the boys are really UIView objects, so I would have to subclass a bunch of different UIView subclasses.

Obviously I could write my own custom class to do this . . . but it feels like Apple must have a simple way to do what I want . . . what am I missing?

The speed of the lookup is important.

One option I thought of was to implement copying as a category on UIView objects, and just have the method retain the object.  But I'm nervous about what side effects this might have.

EDIT: the girls are not UIViews.  They are objects that contain information the boys will want to refer to from time to time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a `CFMutableDictionaryRef` (the Core Foundation equivalent of `NSMutableDictionary`).  You can specify different options about how keys and values behave (like whether they're retained or copied, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Using `[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:]` as the key is a better way, but be really careful that the objects will not be retained so you have to make sure to remove it from the dictionary when you release your original object.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand the model. Is it that you want to be able to map each Boy to a single favorite Girl? So, it would be okay to have a map from Boy to vector of Girl? If so, you could use std::map, std::vector > ... in other words, go over to Objective-C++ and use the Standard Template Library's map and vector containers.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that what you really need is separate model classes for Boys and Girls (then perhaps BoyView and GirlView if they're actually different, otherwise maybe a simple PersonView).

If you have a simple class to represent a Boy or Girl, then you can override `isEqual:` which I *think* would eliminate your issue with NSDictionary copying keys (though I'm not sure I entirely understand your model either).